# TypeScript: transform one interface to another

Tags: typescript

imagine I have two interfaces:

```
interface A {
  foo: boolean,
  bar: string,
  baz: string
}

interface B {
  foo: number,
  bar: string,
  baz: string
}
```

now I have an object that implements interface `A` but I need to pass it to a function that expects interface `B`. Of course I can do:

```
const another_object: B = {
  foo: original_object.foo? 1 : 0,
  bar: original_object.bar,
  baz: original_object.baz
}
```

but if A and B contain many fields this notation would be inconvenient.
Is there any better way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: With the exact same property names ? Seems like you have a design problem... otherwise you can just `interface A extends B` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces

Comment: @WilomGfx Yes, with exact same property names. I'm not sure it this is a design problem. Database I use don't accept booleans, only numbers but in my controller logic I want to operate on booleans. At some point I have to do a transition.

Comment: Your goal here is unclear. Are you trying to reduce the verbosity of the transformation, or are you trying to find a way to completely automate the transformation of a _value_ of type `A` to type `B` that shares all the same properties but not the same types?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - reducing the verbosity was my original goal but if you have a more general solution then of course I'd be happy to learn :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use spread operator to make this a bit easier:

```
const another_object: B = {
   ...original_object,
   foo: orignial_object.foo? 0: 1
}
```

<s>There is a way TypeScript can make this easier. I'll update this answer when that's ready.</s>

UPDATE:
The answer above is sufficient as it is.
What I had in mind is a more restricted use case of overriding properties that has incompatible types while retaining the rest.

If that is what you are looking for, you can check out the `typeOverrideIncompatible()` function in [`type-plus`](https://github.com/unional/type-plus).

The type is a bit complicated.
Here is the main logic:

```
export type ANotB<A extends object, B extends object> =
  IsSame<A, B> extends true ? never :
  IsDisjoint<A, B> extends true ? A :
  {
    [k in Exclude<keyof A, keyof B> | KeysWithDiffType<A, B>]: A[k]
  }
```

`ANotB` is from set theory, meaning properties in `A` but not in `B`.

Comment: [It indeed works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnJge3wC5kAjQgGwjhABocy4oSBnMKUAc3t1LgC9W7LvQC+WLKEixEKAEKYGBYshABXALaloPRs2RsOIbgz6CDw42IkJ8INsjgl0AXkW5cykuzURdvJhIAcj4oIP9GcxCBcKxxW3swMhIFN2wPZAA6bLgIr0dM5WQAfmQARmQSAAYxIA)

Comment: Note that the resulting object will have extra fields from the original through the spread operator. This is assuming that does not hurt and your consuming code is not doing something generic such as `Object.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Database I use don't accept booleans, only numbers but in my controller logic I want to operate on booleans.
>
> – dffsfs

If this is the only transformation necessary, yes, this is possible to achieve using reflection.

```
interface A {
  foo: boolean
  bar: string
  baz: string
}

interface B {
  foo: number
  bar: string
  baz: string
}

type U<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? number : T[K]
}

function toDbObject<T> (value: T): U<T> {
  return Object.entries(value).reduce<Partial<U<T>>>(
    (dbObject: Partial<U<T>>, [key, value]) => Object.assign(
      dbObject, { [key]: typeof value === 'boolean' ? +value : value }
    ),
    {}
  ) as U<T>
}

const a: A = {
  foo: true,
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: 'baz'
}

const b: B = toDbObject(a)
```

Obviously `U` is a poor name for a type here, so you should use a more descriptive name that applies to your use-case.

If your `lib` contains `esnext`, you can use `Array.prototype.map()` and [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) instead of `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

```
function toDbObject<T> (value: T): U<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(value).map(
      ([key, value]) => [key, typeof value === 'boolean' ? +value : value]
    )
  ) as U<T>
}
```